# Conversational intake with ChatGPT support

Tags: openai-api

I am looking for some design advice. My use case is very simple, I would like to collect a users name, email, and gender using a conversational approach. I would like my BOT to ask questions and validate users' responses.

How can this be done with ChatGPT/ OpenAI? I have tried code that will understand the users' inputs and run validations but how do I code a conversational flow?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[image: OpenAI Playground Example]

You can prompt the system to ask specific questions, gather all the information about user and then you could use Guidance; https://github.com/microsoft/guidance .

Guidance can generate a JSON containing all the relevant information from a template.

Also you can use guidance by checking if there's a `null` value in a feld at every step to check if all the information is provided.

Comment: Ok. I think guidance, though it looks great, could be too much for this type of conversational control? Any other simple approach?

Comment: You should use Guidance *after* you collect the data. Then supply that collected data to the ChatGPT with Guidance and extract the "username" etc fields in JSON. The Guidance sould not apply at the every step *in my opinion*. I don't understant how could it effect conversational flow tho.

Comment: Ok, got the guidance part. But what drives the conversation? For e..g. the bot says "what is you name", then users inputs "something", assuming "something" is a valid name how do we go to the next question, say "what is your gender"?

Comment: Ahhh, now I see the problem! You can prompt the "system" by describing what the AI should ask. https://imgur.com/a/yR5sOxO Altough there will be a new problem, how do you know if the conversation is over. I guess you can still use guidance at each step and check if some of the fields are null. https://imgur.com/a/zKrzDkb

Comment: Thanks. That looks very promising. Now I need to figure how it can be done in code?

Comment: I think it's relatively easy using openai-python library. https://github.com/openai/openai-python "User input" part on the other hand...